# How MySQL casts string to boolean?

Tags: mysql, sql

During exploitation of *SQL injection*, I experienced weird behaviour of similar payloads:

- `test' AND SLEEP(5))#` - not worked
- `1test' AND SLEEP(5))#` - worked

I investigated problem and it seems that casting in (My)SQL might be unexpected:

- following expressions result in 0:

  - 1 AND '0'
  - 1 AND '00'
  - 1 AND 'x'
  - 1 AND 'xx'
  - 1 AND 'x0'
  - 1 AND 'x1'
  - 1 AND '0x'
- and these result in 1:

  - 1 AND '1'
  - 1 AND '11'
  - **1 AND '1x'**

You can verify it with [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb/20237).

I am wondering what is the reason behind such behaviour. Is it documented or is there any reference on this?

Comment: better injection would be the + sign `'test' + SLEEP(5)` or `'1test' + SLEEP(5)` always executes.

Comment: @RaymondNijland good point! Currently sqlmap tool lacks of this payload type, so maybe I will prepare it.

Answer (score 2):

You would appear to have a `where` condition such as:

```
where 'test' and sleep(5)
```

This is ridiculous, isn't it?  A string where a boolean expression should be.  If you were a database, the proper thing to do is to return an error of the sort that "'test' doesn't make sense here!".

But, MySQL is more generous and forgiving.  Instead, it treats the string as a *number* and does silent conversion.  Because the number has no leading digits, the conversion produces `0`.  Numbers are allowed in a boolean context.  `0` happens to be the numeric way of saying "false".

So,

```
where 'test' and sleep(5)
```

evaluates to:

```
where false and sleep(5)
```

The "false" short-circuits the `and` and the second expression is not evaluated.

Similarly,

```
where '1test' and sleep(5)
```

evaluates to:

```
where true and sleep(5)
```

There is no short-circuiting and the second expression is evaluated.

Comment: I know there is such conversion, but I asked about documentation / reference.

Answer (score 1):

We just had a similar issue and with a bit of tinkering we found out how the check works.

It appears that when evaluating a string as a boolean during a where it takes the following steps:

1. find first non-numeric character and take all numeric characters which are in front of it
2. if value of this number is higher then zero it will return true, otherwise it will return false